# Sass mixing uses last class out of all it made

Tags: sass

I have this mixin:

```
$distance: 30px
  
@mixin animate($delay: 0s, $direction: "up")
  animation: fadeIn 1s
  animation-delay: $delay
  animation-fill-mode: both
  
  @keyframes fadeIn
    from
      opacity: 0
      @if $direction == "up"
        transform: translateY($distance)
      
      @else if $direction == "down"
        transform: translateY(-$distance)
      
      @else if $direction == "left"
        transform: translateX($distance)
      
      @else if $direction == "right"
        transform: translateX(-$distance)
    to
      opacity: 1
      transform: translateY(0) translateX(0)

.animate-up
  @include animate(0s, "up")

.animate-down
  @include animate(0s, 'down')

.animate-left
  @include animate(0s, 'left')

.animate-right
  @include animate(0s, 'right')
```

and it somehow makes that whichever class I use from this four it always uses the value from the last uncommented class. So if you use `animate-down` it will use `animate-right`'s value.

I think I'm not getting something here about making mixins.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that `keyframes` were not included inside the class, but rather kept outside so they were overwriting each other.

Here is the solution I made up:

```
$distance: 30px
  
@mixin animate($delay: 0s, $direction: "down")
  animation: fade-in-#{$direction} 1s
  animation-delay: $delay
  animation-fill-mode: both
  
  @keyframes fade-in-#{$direction}
    from
      opacity: 0
      @if $direction == "up"
        transform: translateY($distance)
      
      @else if $direction == "down"
        transform: translateY(-$distance)
      
      @else if $direction == "left"
        transform: translateX($distance)
      
      @else if $direction == "right"
        transform: translateX(-$distance)
    to
      opacity: 1
      transform: translateY(0) translateX(0)
```

Generated CSS:

```
.animate-up {
  animation: fade-in-up 1s;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes fade-in-up {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
  }
}

.animate-down {
  animation: fade-in-down 1s;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes fade-in-down {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
  }
}
etc.
```